# OpenCV-Python - How to format numpy arrays when using calibration functions

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, opencv3.0, camera-calibration

I'm trying to calibrate a fisheye camera using OpenCV 3.0.0 python bindings (with an asymmetric circle grid), but I have problems to format the object and image point arrays correctly. My current source looks like this:

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np


def main():
    circle_diameter = 4.5
    circle_radius = circle_diameter/2.0
    pattern_width = 4
    pattern_height = 11
    num_points = pattern_width*pattern_height

    images = glob.glob('*.bmp')
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

    imgpoints = []
    objpoints = []
    obj = []

    for i in range(pattern_height):
        for j in range(pattern_width):
            obj.append((
                 float(2*j + i % 2)*circle_radius,
                 float(i*circle_radius),
                 0
            ))

    for name in images:
        image = cv2.imread(name)
        grayimage = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        retval, centers = cv2.findCirclesGrid(grayimage, (pattern_width, pattern_height), flags=(cv2.CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID + cv2.CALIB_CB_CLUSTERING))

        imgpoints_tmp = np.zeros((num_points, 2))
        if retval:
            for i in range(num_points):
                imgpoints_tmp[i, 0] = centers[i, 0, 0]
                imgpoints_tmp[i, 1] = centers[i, 0, 1]

            imgpoints.append(imgpoints_tmp)
            objpoints.append(obj)


    # Convertion to numpy array
    imgpoints = np.array(imgpoints, dtype=np.float32)
    objpoints = np.array(objpoints, dtype=np.float32)

    K, D = cv2.fisheye.calibrate(objpoints, imgpoints, image_size=(1280, 800), K=None, D=None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error message is:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (objectPoints.type() == CV_32FC3 || objectPoints.type() == CV_64FC3) in cv::fisheye::calibrate
```

`objpoints` has shape `(31,44,3)`.

So `objpoints` array needs to be formatted in a different way, but I'm not able to achieve the correct layout. Maybe someone can help here?

Comment: this is currently an issue with cv2.fisheye bindings. https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5534

Answer (score 2):

In the sample of OpenCV ([Camera Calibration](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html)) they set the objp to `objp2 = np.zeros((8*9,3), np.float32)`

However, in omnidirectional camera or fisheye camera, it should be:
`objp = np.zeros((1,8*9,3), np.float32)`

Idea is from here [Calibrate fisheye lens using OpenCV — part 1](https://medium.com/@kennethjiang/calibrate-fisheye-lens-using-opencv-333b05afa0b0)

Answer (score 0):

The correct layout of `objpoints` is a list of numpy arrays with `len(objpoints) = "number of pictures"` and each entry beeing a numpy array.

Please have a look at [the official help](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera). OpenCV documentation talks about "vectors", which is equivalent of a list or numpy.array. In this instance a "vector of vectors" can be interpreted as a list of numpy.arrays.

Comment: What length is each vector? 2 or 3 element?

Answer (score 0):

The data type is correct, but the shape is not. The expected shape of `objpoints` supposed to be `(n_observations, 1, n_corners_per_observation, 3)`. Therefore, the code in your case should be:

```
imgpoints = np.array(imgpoints, dtype=np.float32).reshape(
  -1, 
  1, 
  pattern_width * pattern_height, 
  3
)
```

or more general:

```
imgpoints = np.array(imgpoints, dtype=np.float32).reshape(
  n_observations, 
  1, 
  n_corners_per_observation, 
  3
)
```

The error message is slightly misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find a satisfying answer here so I messed around and eventually got this chunk to work:

```
calibration_flags = cv2.fisheye.CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC + cv2.fisheye.CALIB_CHECK_COND + cv2.fisheye.CALIB_FIX_SKEW

# lists with each element a [1,n_points,_] array of type float32
obj_points = [np.random.rand(1,10,3).astype(np.float32)]
fisheye_points = [np.random.rand(1,10,2).astype(np.float32)]

# initialize empty variables of correct size and type, where total_num_points is summed across all arrays in each above list
rvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float32) for i in range(total_num_points)]
tvecs = [np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.float32) for i in range(total_num_points)]
D = np.zeros([4,1]).astype(np.float32)
K = np.zeros([3,3]).astype(np.float32)

outputs = cv2.fisheye.calibrate(gt_points,fisheye_points,(1920,1080),K,D,rvecs,tvecs)
```